# How to make sure that onCreateView is called when a Fragment changes in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I use ViewPager with a custom PagerAdapter (StaticPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter).
The problem is: when I change the Fragment1 with Fragment3, onCreateView is not called and findViewById(R.id.placeholder) returns null

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAdapter.startUpdate(mPager);
    mAdapter.setFragment(0, new DummyFragment3());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mAdapter.finishUpdate(mPager);

    TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
    tv.setText("PLACEHOLDER");
}
```

A solution can be to move

```
TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
tv.setText("PLACEHOLDER");
```

on the onCreateView in the Fragment, but unfortunately I can not do that.

Question: How to make sure that onCreateView is called right after a Fragment changes in the ViewPager?

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!
below all the codes

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

StaticPagerAdapter mAdapter;
 ViewPager mPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mAdapter = new StaticPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),2);

    mAdapter.setTitle(0,"EXPENSES");
    mAdapter.setTitle(1,"CONTACTS");
    mAdapter.setFragment(0, new DummyFragment1());
    mAdapter.setFragment(1, new DummyFragment2());

    SlidingTabLayout mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAdapter.startUpdate(mPager);
    mAdapter.setFragment(0, new DummyFragment3());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mAdapter.finishUpdate(mPager);

    TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
    tv.setText("PLACEHOLDER");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

StaticPagerAdapter

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public class StaticPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    String[] titels;
    Fragment[] fragments;
    public StaticPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
        super(fm);
        titels = new String[size];
        fragments = new Fragment[size];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (fragments!=null & position< fragments.length)
            return fragments[position];
        return new Fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (titels!=null && position<titels.length)
            return titels[position];
        return "";
    }

    public void setTitle(int position, String title) {
        if (titels!=null && position<titels.length)
            titels[position]=title;
    }

    public void setFragment(int position, Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragments!=null && position<fragments.length)
            fragments[position]=fragment;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titels.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

DummyFragment1

```
public class DummyFragment1 extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dummy, container, false);
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Fragment number 1");

        return view;


    }
}
```

LayoutFragment1

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

DummyFragment3

```
public class DummyFragment3 extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dummy, container, false);
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Fragment number 3");

        return view;


    }
```

LayoutFragment3

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

---

I also added some Logs.d messages to check the order

In the Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mAdapter = new StaticPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),2);

    Log.d("msg","1");
    mAdapter.setTitle(0,"EXPENSES");
    mAdapter.setTitle(1,"CONTACTS");
    mAdapter.setFragment(0, new DummyFragment1());
    mAdapter.setFragment(1, new DummyFragment2());

    SlidingTabLayout mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Log.d("msg", "2");
    mAdapter.startUpdate(mPager);
    mAdapter.setFragment(0, new DummyFragment3());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mAdapter.finishUpdate(mPager);

    Log.d("msg", "4");
    //TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
    //tv.setText("PLACEHOLDER");
}
```

Fragment3

```
public class DummyFragment3 extends Fragment{

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Log.d("msg", "3");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dummy, container, false);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Fragment number 3");

    return view;


}
}
```

But the order is

```
D/msg: 1
D/msg: 2
D/msg: 4
D/msg: 3
```

I am expecting that when I change Fragment in the PagerAdapter, onCreateView of that Fragment is called, but this actually happens later.
Thanks for all the inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the order of execution of processes by placing a print instruction in the Log

Example

Log.d ("msg", "Throwable");

Put differents MSG and check the order.

Comment: Hi Josedlujan, thanks for the quick response. I add the Log.d messages in the questions: I am expecting that when I change Fragment in the PagerAdapter, onCreateView of that Fragment is called, but this actually happens after that. Thanks for any comments will help

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, I will post it here in case someone has the same problem. The trick is to use instantiateItem when you change the Fragment using this sequence.

startUpdate will start a transaction in the FragmentManager

instantiateItem will attach or add the Fragment in the transaction of FragmentManager

finishUpdate will call executePendingTransactions of FragmentManager, which will at the end finally call OnCreateView of the Fragment.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Log.d("msg", "2");

    Fragment tmp = new DummyFragment3();
    mAdapter.setFragment(0, tmp);
    mAdapter.startUpdate(mPager);
    mAdapter.instantiateItem(mPager, 0);
    mAdapter.finishUpdate(mPager);

    Log.d("msg", "4");
    TextView tv = (TextView) mPager.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
    tv.setText("PLACEHOLDER");
}
```

And the most important thing is to overwrite the method getItemId in your implementation of FragmentPagerAdapter with something that returns a unique key for each Fragment you want to display.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).hashCode();
}
```

The original getItemId just returns the position, which is fine if you don't have to change the pages inside ViewPager.

Hope it helps